# X-editable in loop

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code in view:

```
    <?php foreach ($display as $disp): ?>
   <td><a href="#" id="name" data-type="text" data-pk="<?php echo $disp->id;?>" data-url="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl;?>/product/update" ><?=$disp->name?></a></td>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

This shows all the names but only first name is editable with x-editable.

here is the javascripts used:

```
 $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline'; 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#name').editable();     
    });
```

Comment: The ID must be unique across your document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID must be unique. this could have done with class.

```
<?php foreach ($display as $disp): ?>
   <td><a href="#" class="name" data-type="text" data-pk="<?php echo $disp->id;?>" data-url="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl;?>/product/update" ><?=$disp->name?></a></td>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

and,

```
   $('.name').editable();
```